# Turn above an X symbol in Chopin’s prelude in E minor

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, classical-music

I am a self-taught pianist and thought I would pick this piece up relatively easily and quickly, but being self-taught I often run into unknown signs, symbols, and other things like that, that give me trouble. I believe I know the sideways S to be a turn, but it is placed above an X-like symbol and this leaves me confused. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Chopin Prelude in E minor]

Answer (score 9):

the x stands for a double sharp (instead of ##)

[image]

**Turn:** (look example 4 of the picture below)

now the ornament (turn) behind the quarter above the x  - look at the fingering - will be played at the second eight of the note A and 4312  means that you play after A# an eight note length

the the turn B-A♯-Gx-A♯

**fingerings:**

4=B

3=A#

1=Gx or G## which is the same key as A

2=A#

[image]

Comment: I have seen turns above notes, but never to the side, and am familiar with double sharps, but I’ve only ever  seen them placed directly before specific notes. My confusion was with those things and your explanation helped, thank you.

Comment: @Albrecht Hügli, I have edited the answer. I have removed this sentence "as we are in E the third G is already altered to G# (the 4 signs are F#,C#.G#,D#)" since the prelude is in E minor and thus only have one sharp F♯. I have also changed B-A-Gx-A into B-A♯-Gx-A♯.

Comment: Note that my edit awaits to be peer reviewed before it appears in the post. So we will see what happens.